# Network request failed while using Fetch in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am getting the following error when i try to fetch API from my local server

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (blob:http://localhost:8081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:15823:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (blob:http://localhost:8081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:17900:39)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (blob:http://localhost:8081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:17655:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (blob:http://localhost:8081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:17482:16)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:17592:47
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (blob:http://localhost:8081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:3478:37)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (blob:http://localhost:8081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:2384:44)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:2154:17
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (blob:http://localhost:8081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:2346:11)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http://localhost:8081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:2153:14) {stack: TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRe…081/9b6428f5-4e65-45a0-9490-3852c365f0df:2153:14),
message: Network request failed}
```

I am accessing the APi from my client as follows

```
const apiURL = "192.168.1.5:3000/api/";


     fetch(apiURL + '/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: this.props.username,

                    password: this.props.password
                })
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    console.log(responseJson);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

I am running the app on my actual device which runs in android 7.0.Both my laptop and mobile are connected on the same Wi-Fi. I check my manifest file and yes Internet permission was enabled. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try with `http://192.168.1.5:3000/api/`?

Comment: thanks bennygenel. I really forgot the basics seems like